# Algolia autocomplete react-native

Tags: react-native, algolia

I'm looking for a way to implement Algolia Autocomplete for react-native application. sadly i can't find any react-native doc or example for this.

so i tried to follow react [documentaion](https://www.algolia.com/doc/ui-libraries/autocomplete/api-reference/autocomplete-core/createAutocomplete/) but with no luck the query doesn't seem to work.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

import { createAutocomplete } from '@algolia/autocomplete-core';
import { getAlgoliaResults } from '@algolia/autocomplete-preset-algolia';

import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch/lite';


const searchClient = algoliasearch(APP_ID, API_KEY);

interface AutocompleteProps {
  query: string;
}

const Autocomplete: React.FC<AutocompleteProps> = ({ query }) => {
  const [autocompleteState, setAutocompleteState] = React.useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    autocomplete.setIsOpen(true);
    autocomplete.setQuery(query);
    return () => {
      autocomplete.setIsOpen(false);
    };
  }, [query]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('autocompleteState result', autocompleteState);
  }, [autocompleteState]);

  const autocomplete = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      createAutocomplete({
        onStateChange({ state }) {
          // (2) Synchronize the Autocomplete state with the React state.
          setAutocompleteState(state);
        },
        getSources() {
          return [
            {
              getItemInputValue({ item }) {
                return item.query;
              },
              getItems({ query }) {
                return getAlgoliaResults({
                  searchClient,
                  queries: [
                    {
                      indexName: 'my_index',
                      query,
                      params: {
                        hitsPerPage: 4
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                });
              },
              getItemUrl({ item }) {
                return item.url;
              }
            }
          ];
        }
      }),
    []
  );
  return <View />;
};

export default Autocomplete;
```

I'm not sure even if this is possible with react-native.

Any help will be highly appreciated

thank you